# Linq filter by multiple values that may or may not exist

Tags: c#, linq, list, filter

I'm sure this question has been asked before but I haven't been able to find it.
I want to filter a list of table names depending on several criteria that will ultimately be determined by the user. Following is my current code.

```
private List<TableMetaData> tableMetaData = new List<TableMetaData>();
public class TableMetaData
{
    public string TableName;
    public string ReferenceTableName;
    public bool IsAuditTable;
    public bool IsSyncTable;
    public bool IsView;
}
public List<string> GetTableNames(TableMetaData filterData)
{
    List<string> filteredNames = tableMetaData
        .Where(table => (table.IsAuditTable == filterData.IsAuditTable)
            && (table.IsSyncTable == filterData.IsSyncTable)
            && (table.IsView == filterData.IsView))
        .Select(table => table.TableName).ToList();

    return filteredNames;
}
```

I still need to include TableMetaData.TableName and TableMetaData.ReferenceTableName in the filtering operation. These values, however, could be null, in which case they would not be used in the filter. I figure there must be a more simple way of doing this than writing a separate linq statement for each condition?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ? operator to help you with this as the following:

```
public List<string> GetTableNames(TableMetaData filterData)
{
    List<string> filteredNames = tableMetaData
        .Where(table => (table.IsAuditTable == filterData.IsAuditTable)
            && (table.IsSyncTable == filterData.IsSyncTable)
            && (table.IsView == filterData.IsView)
            && (filterData.ReferenceTableName == null ? true : table.ReferenceTableName == filterData.ReferenceTableName)
            && (filterData.TableName == null ? true : table.TableName == filterData.TableName))
        .Select(table => table.TableName).ToList();

    return filteredNames;
}
```

Comment: This will work well for me. I think this solution is more readable than using a mix of and and or operators. Thank you.

Comment: @user1165224 Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

You can use separate `Where` calls, which makes it more readable (in my opinion)

```
var nameQuery = tableMetaData
    .Where(table => (table.IsAuditTable == filterData.IsAuditTable)
        && (table.IsSyncTable == filterData.IsSyncTable)
        && (table.IsView == filterData.IsView));

if (filterData.TableName != null)
     nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(table => table.TableName == filterData.TableName);

if (filterData.ReferenceTableName != null)
     nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(table => table.ReferenceTableName == filterData.ReferenceTableName);

// more criteria ..

return  nameQuery.Select(table => table.TableName).ToList();
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, but it will not compile. nameQuery becomes an item of type LIst<> and cannot be set in the second filter because the result is of type IEnumerable<>. An easy thing to fix, but I thought there might be a more simple solution.

Comment: This of course is the right answer. +1 @user1165224 There is no way `nameQuery` to become `List<T>` if you don't call `ToList()`.

Comment: I typed in the above and didn't get an error (correcting for the parentheses). I must have done something funny the first time. If I had any more criteria, I would prefer breaking them out to make it more readable than one long linq statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this. Just apply the null check in an or clause before the actual condition.

Example:

```
public List<string> GetTableNames(TableMetaData filterData)
{
    List<string> filteredNames = tableMetaData
        .Where(table => (table.IsAuditTable == filterData.IsAuditTable)
            && (table.IsSyncTable == filterData.IsSyncTable)
            && (table.IsView == filterData.IsView)
            && ((table.TableName == null) || (table.TableName == "Something"))
            && ((table.ReferenceTableName == null) || (table.ReferenceTableName == "Something")))
        .Select(table => table.TableName).ToList();
    return filteredNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method to determine whether any of these strings are `null` or empty ("") before using them. Something like this:

```
public List<string> GetTableNames(TableMetaData filterData)
{
    List<string> filteredNames = tableMetaData
        .Where(table => (table.IsAuditTable == filterData.IsAuditTable)
            && (table.IsSyncTable == filterData.IsSyncTable)
            && (table.IsView == filterData.IsView)
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterData.ReferenceTableName) || table.TableName == filterData.TableName)
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterData.ReferenceTableName) || table.ReferenceTableName == filterData.ReferenceTableName))
        .Select(table => table.TableName).ToList();

    return filteredNames;
}
```